# Nested breakpoint-sass with Susy span mixin

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass, susy-sass, breakpoint-sass

I use nested breakpoint with Susy. The compiled CSS contain the line: box-sizing: ;
When I don't use nested breakpoint the compiled CSS is correct.

The SASS code:

```
@include border-box-sizing;
#list {
    $map: (
        columns: 12,
        gutters: 1/3,
        math: fluid,
        output: float,
        last-flow: from,
        global-box-sizing: border-box,
        gutter-position: after
    );
@include layout($map);
@include clearfix;
> li {
    background: #BAC7D1;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    @include span(3);
    @include breakpoint(max-width 1099px) {
        @include span(4);// this line make the problem: "box-sizing: ;"
    }
    &:nth-child(4n+4) {
        @include breakpoint(1100px) {
            @include span(3 last);
            background: blue;
        }
    }
    &:nth-child(3n+3) {
        @include breakpoint(max-width 1099px) {
            @include span(4 last);
            background: greenyellow;
        }
    }
}
```

The compiled CSS (with the line: box-sizing: ;):

```
#gallery-list {
    overflow: hidden;
    *zoom: 1;
}
#gallery-list > li {
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    width: 23.40426%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2.12766%;
}
@media  (max-width: 68.6875em) {
    #gallery-list > li {
        box-sizing: ;
        width: 31.91489%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 2.12766%;
    }
}
@media  (min-width: 68.75em) {
    #gallery-list > li:nth-child(4n+4) {
        box-sizing: ;
        width: 23.40426%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
@media  (max-width: 68.6875em) {
    #gallery-list > li:nth-child(3n+3) {
        box-sizing: ;
        width: 31.91489%;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```

I've also used nested breakpoints with Susy in another site and it works well. I've also tried the susy-breakpoint mixin the problem remains the same.

Comment: I can't recreate this, but it looks like a problem with `null`-handling in Sass. What version of Sass are you using?

Comment: @Eric M Suzanne I use gulp-sass. Sorry I'm unable to find the version of Sass. I've installed Susy, Breakpoint-sass and Compass with Bower. I just run a Bower update that has updated Susy from 2.2.2 to 2.2.5. After I've re-compiled the css and the box-sizing no longer appears. Solved problem.